# Ideas for clustering implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am implementing a clustering algorithm. I have a `vector of Node` objects to keep original copies and another `vector of Cluster` objects: Each `Cluster object` holds a `vector of pointers` to all the nodes it contains.

In every iteration two Clusters are supposed to be joined together according to their joining cost.

Right now I use a `priority queue` to hold structs that contain a joining cost and pointers to both of the clusters. In every iteration I pop the one with the minimal cost and join the referenced clusters. I want to use a queue, because I have a lot of data amd looping over all the objects to find a minimum cost is not practical.

I have implemented the merging by copying the data from one cluster to another and then removing one of the clusters. The problem is that my queue now contains a lot of entries that reference the removed cluster.

How would you implement it? Maybe there is some more clever way of joining the clusters? I am looking for a genereal idea for the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following idea. Let's add a field `bool _isRemoved` to the `Cluster` class . You will set it to `true` for every removed cluster. When you pop something from the queue, you will firstly check if any of two clusters has `_isRemoved` set to `true`. If yes you should just pop the next pair from the queue and continue processing.

I'm not C++ expert but the next problem might be that clusters that were removed and are referenced still occupies a memory. If you want to avoid this problem instead of storing pointers to clusters in the queue you can store identifiers of clusters. Identifiers can be quickly mapped to clusters by using a map (a dictionary).